# Self Join SQL Server with aggregates

Tags: sql-server, self-join

I have a query that returns all sessions started on the current day and then gives me counts for current active sessions and time since last login. (This lets me know if any kernals develop any issues causing users being unable to login)

```
SELECT [server]
     , appserver
     , count(*) as open_sessions
     , max(start_time) Latest_New_Login
     , datediff(minute, max(start_time) , GETDATE() ) elapsed_mins_since_last_login
FROM [session_logs]
where DATEDIFF(day, START_TIME, GETDATE()) <= 0  
and end_time is null
group by server, appserver
order by 1,2
```

Data Returned

```
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| server  | appserver | open_sessions |    Latest_New_Login     | Elapsed_mins_since_last_login |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
| SERVER1 | PK1       |            13 | 2018-01-26 16:24:47.087 |                             1 |
| SERVER1 | PK2       |            12 | 2018-01-26 16:19:00.157 |                             6 |
| SERVER2 | PK1       |             8 | 2018-01-26 16:25:41.297 |                             0 |
| SERVER2 | PK2       |             6 | 2018-01-26 16:07:31.027 |                            18 |
| SERVER3 | PK1       |             7 | 2018-01-26 16:18:56.597 |                             7 |
| SERVER3 | PK2       |             5 | 2018-01-26 16:19:06.550 |                             6 |
+---------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

All well and good, 
however i need a workaround to ensure that all the servers, and app servers are shown.  We had a issue today where no active logins were showing on Server 3 PK1 and this removed its entry from my results table.

Is there a way i can get the below data set always showing and have my aggregate functions tallying against them?  A self joining query but I can't get it working.

```
select distinct [server], appserver
FROM [session_logs]
```

returns values

```
Server 1 PK1
Server 1 PK2
Server 2 PK1
Server 2 PK2
Server 3 PK1
Server 3 PK2
```

Comment: Do you have a table that knows all the servers? Would make it much simpler problem than self joins.

Comment: Can't find the table (if it exists) and unable to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    serv.[server],
    serv.appserver,
    t.open_sessions,
    t.Latest_New_Login,
    t.elapsed_mins_since_last_login
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [server], appserver FROM [session_logs]
) serv
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [server]
         , appserver
         , COUNT(*) AS open_sessions
         , MAX(start_time) AS Latest_New_Login
         , DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAX(start_time), GETDATE()) AS elapsed_mins_since_last_login
    FROM [session_logs]
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(day, START_TIME, GETDATE()) <= 0  
        AND end_time is null
    GROUP BY [server], appserver
) t
    ON t.[server] = serv.[server]
    AND t.appserver = serv.appserver
ORDER BY
    serv.[server], serv.appserver
```

If you have a table that holds the list of your servers, use that instead of:

`SELECT DISTINCT [server], appserver FROM [session_logs]`

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to work.  Will do further testing tonight.

Comment: No worries. You might want to look at the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another option without using `JOIN`

```
select
    [server]
    , appserver
    , count(start_time) as open_sessions
    , max(start_time) Latest_New_Login
    , datediff(minute, max(start_time) , GETDATE() ) elapsed_mins_since_last_login
from (
    SELECT [server]
         , appserver
        , start_time
    FROM 
        [session_logs]
    where 
        DATEDIFF(day, START_TIME, GETDATE()) <= 0  
        and end_time is null
    union all select distinct [server], appserver, null FROM [session_logs]
) t
group by server, appserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a Common Table Expression with all the unique servers and LEFT JOIN on it:

```
;with cte([server], appserver)
as (
    select distinct [server], appserver
    from [session_logs]
    -- let's limit with records from last 30 days in case [session_logs] is a massive table
    -- I assume all servers you care about had some activity in that time
    where DATEDIFF(day, START_TIME, GETDATE()) <= 30
)
SELECT cte.[server]
     , cte.appserver
     , count(start_time) as open_sessions
     , max(start_time) Latest_New_Login
     , datediff(minute, max(start_time), GETDATE()) Elapsed_mins_since_last_login
FROM cte
left join [session_logs] as sl on cte.[server] = sl.[server] and cte.appserver = sl.appserver
where DATEDIFF(day, START_TIME, GETDATE()) <= 0  
and end_time is null
group by cte.[server], cte.appserver
order by cte.[server], cte.appserver
```